# How can I infinitely increase an expected RPS load pattern like the one defined in the Throughput Shaping Timer?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jsr223, threadgroup

I am using Jmeter 5.2.1 along with Concurrency Thread Group with ${__tstFeedback(ThroughputShapingTimer,1,10,10)} in combination with the Throughput Shaping Timer to dynamically change the target throughput throughout the test duration.

I want to create a stress test scenario configuration in which I define a start TPS X, hold the target TPS by Y minutes and then increase the target TPS to Z value, hold the target TPS by Y minutes again and then increase the TPS by a Z value again; And I want to do this infinitely until some errors start showing up.

Something like this, but with the ability to keep repeating a defined pattern forever:
[image]

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special JMeter property called [`load_profile`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) where you can define the desired load pattern, something like:

```
step(1,9,1,2m)
```

will generate 9 steps like yours at the image, change this `9` to whatever number you like and it will generate and apply the required pattern.

The property can be passed to JMeter via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jload_profile="step(1,9,1,2m)" -n -t test.jmx ...
```

or if you want to make the change permanent you can put it to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/).

Comment: So if I pass this special JMeter property called load_profile from the command line, will it override the load profile configured in the jmeter GUI-mode Test plan? I mean, if I have the load pattern defined as shown in the screenshot, save and close the GUI mode and then call the jmeter script from the cmd command line with this property, will it override whatever I configured in the Throughput Shaping Timer in the GUI?

Comment: Yes. The load_profile property will override the existing load profiles defined in all throughput shaping timers. You can experiment with this will a sample test plan and apply it to the production.